# Convert Nested List to Set using a Recursive Function

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, recursion, time

I need to create a recursive function (for simplicity) that takes any nested list and returns a set of unique elements.

To tackle this, I decided to first create a function that takes a list and converts it to a set:

```
ranList = [2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3]

def eue(ranList):
    newList = set(ranList)
    return print(newList)
```

Easy enough, it works. Now to create a function that takes a nested list and returns a 2-D list (this is a recursive function I found using search on this site) and a function that takes the other function, and returns a set containing unique elements:

```
lis = [['c', 'd'], 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, ['c']]

from collections import Iterable

def flatten(lis):
    for item in lis:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):
            for x in flatten(item):
                yield x
        else:        
            yield item

def eue(lis):
    newSet = set(flatten(lis))
    print(newSet)
```

Now, by calling eue(), it solves my original question. But I want to make it much more simplistic.

How would I go about combining these functions to produce a single function that reduces the amount of computing time it takes to run?

Thanks.

Comment: Since the original `flatten` is a generator, you're unlikely to get to significant a speedup from combining it into a single function.  Unless this is a significant bottleneck in the program that you can demonstrate, I'd probably not worry about trying to optimize this...

Comment: You are returning None in your function  `eue`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, you're right, thanks for noticing that. I'll fix it asap.

Comment: You can also   `yield from flatten(item)` using python3

Comment: you want it to run faster: write a C extension, you want it to be simpler: use `yield from flatten(item)`, not sure if you can get much nicer then you have though.

Comment: If you had prior knowledge about what it contained you could get a significant speed up removing the Iterable and changing the logic to something else that is a lot more efficient but it depends on whether you would have custom types or not

Answer (score 1):

you can use `itertools.chain` to link all the iterators together:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Iterable

def isIter(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, Iterable) and not isinstance(obj,str)
def flatten(it):
    seqs = (flatten(item) if isIter(item) else (item,) for item in it)
    return chain(*seqs)
def enu1(it):
    return set(gen(it))
```

Although this means that for every non-sequence element you have to make a tuple with that one item `(item,)` for chain to work properly, not sure how much of an effect it would have on performance.

You can reduce this to a single function (other then `isIter`) by converting to a set:

```
def enu2_A(it):
    seqs = (enu2_A(item) if isIter(item) else (item,) for item in it)
    return set(chain(*seqs))
```

But again this creates a new `set` object for every recursive call to `enu`, maybe add an option to convert?

```
def enu2(it,return_set = True):
    seqs = (enu2(item,False) if isIter(item) else (item,) for item in it)
    if return_set:
        return set(chain(*seqs))
    else:
        return chain(*seqs)
```

but combining it into a single function really doesn't give much speed boost at all:

```
import timeit

a = timeit.timeit("enu1(lis)","from __main__ import enu1,lis",number=10000)
b = timeit.timeit("enu2(lis)","from __main__ import enu2,lis",number=10000)

print(a,b)
print(a/b) #ratio, more then 1 means a took longer
```

output:

```
0.3400449920009123 0.32908301999850664
1.0333106582115827
```

so 3% faster by combining into a single function, I'm guessing that wasn't the speed up you were expecting, your code is very efficient as it is and much more pythonesque then mine so I wouldn't change it.

---

EDIT: just did a benchmark of my `enu2` and your `enu` - **your method is faster then the one I have provided by about 16%**, leave it as it is as you can't get much better other then moving to python2 and using `compiler.ast.flatten` or another C level equivelent:

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(lis):
    for item in lis:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):
            for x in flatten(item):
                yield x
        else:        
            yield item

def enu(obj):
    return set(flatten(obj))

lis = [['c', 'd'], 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, ['c']]

import timeit

a = timeit.timeit("enu(lis)","from __main__ import enu,lis",number=10000)

b = timeit.timeit("set(ast.flatten(lis))","from __main__ import lis ; from compiler import ast",number=10000)

print(a,b)
print(a/b)
```

output:

```
0.3324121500045294 0.28561264199379366
1.1638565705076622
```

so doing the operation in C sped up the process by 4X, however the `compiler` package has been out of date since 2.6 according to [the docs](http://Deprecated%20since%20version%202.6:%20The%20compiler%20package%20has%20been%20removed%20in%20Python%203.):

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The compiler package has been removed in Python 3.

so it is quite possible that if you wrote `flatten` in a C extension you could get even better results but if you want to write code in pure python you have about as good as you can get.